# JNI C Reflection puzzle

Tags: java, c, reflection, java-native-interface

All code below works as expected, except for the indicated line that crashes.
I have spent days scratching my head over this code, checking and re-checking the documentation. I would be delighted if someone could point out the no doubt obvious thing I'm missing.

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test tst = new Test();
        System.out.println((String)tst.test());
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    static { System.loadLibrary("test"); }
    public native Object test();
}
```

test.c

```
#include <jni.h>
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Test_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    const char* out = "success";
    do {
        jclass cls_cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Class");
        if ( !cls_cls ) { out = "FindClass"; break; }
        jmethodID mfn = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(
            env, cls_cls, "forName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;"
        );
        if ( !mfn ) { out = "GetStaticMethodID"; break; }
        // **** lines above succeed, line below segfaults ****
        jclass cls = (jclass) (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(
            env, cls_cls, mfn, "java.lang.String"
        );
        if ( (*env)->ExceptionCheck(env) ) { out = "CallStaticObjectMethod"; break; }
    } while ( 0 );
    (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
    return (jobject) (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, out);
}
```

compile/exec

```
gcc -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -Wall -c test.c -o test.o -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux
gcc -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -Wall -shared -o libtest.so -O test.o
javac -Xlint:all Main.java
java -Xcheck:jni -Djava.library.path=. Main
```

Expected outcome, expressed in pure Java:

```
Class<?> cls_cls = Class.class;
Method mfn = cls_cls.getDeclaredMethod("forName", String.class);
Class<?> cls = (Class) mfn.invoke(null, "java.lang.String");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke the `Class.forName` method you should pass a `java.lang.String` to it, not a raw `const char*`.

To get a Java String from the C string use the `NewStringUTF` function:

```c
jstring arg = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "java.lang.String");
jclass cls = (jclass) (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(
    env, cls_cls, mfn, arg
);
```

Then the java code from `Main.java` will print:

```
success
```

Comment: Definitely a ["Doh!"](https://c.tenor.com/muj4RR_sPl0AAAAd/homer-simpson-les-simpson.gif) moment.  ;-)  (I may have a few of those in my own past...)

Comment: @caco3 Thank you so much for reviewing the code: I'd reached that point where I was looking and looking but just couldn't see anything wrong with it. Your time is very much appreciated.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Definitely, and not the first, but rarely have I been happier to slap my forehead. :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I think I have them every day, or at least every week:)